# ASP.Net Core: X-Frame-Options strange behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, x-frame-options

I need to remove `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` header from some of my actions which should render a content for an iframe. As long as it is added to requests by default I disabled it in `Startup.cs`: `services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false);`. Then I wrote a simple middleware:

```
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");

        await next();
    });
```

Actions needed to answer to cross-domain requests are decorated with result filter attribute:

```
    public class SuppresXFrameOptionFilter : ResultFilterAttribute
    {
        public override async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context,
ResultExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");

            await next();
        }
    }
```

Here comes the weiredness. First cross-domain request fails because despite the filter works as expected in the end the `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` is still present in the response (I checked it after `next()` in the middleware - the header reappeared). If I press F5 the header is no longer in the response and everything works as it should. That happens only with `X-Frame-Options` header, a custom one is removed correctly.
What makes the `X-Frame-Options` which has been removed appear in a response again?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I would say on the first request [Antiforgery](https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/blob/2fcb187d7d34e9a0b046c2502c3a8b9b0155db91/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery/Internal/DefaultAntiforgery.cs#L264) saves the cookie which means it also tries to set the `X-Frame-Options` header.

If you want to disable that header in Antiforgery and manually handle it yourself, what you want is setting `SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader` **to be true** ;)

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);
```