# UseExceptionHandler() middleware in .NET Core MVC prevents response headers setting

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

`Startup.cs`:

```
// ...
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Server", "ololo");

    await next();
});

if (env.IsDevelopment()) { app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage(); }
else { app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error"); }

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAuthentication();
// ...
```

When everything is fine, I get the following headers, as expected:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2018 18:39:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: ololo
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

So `Server`, `X-Frame-Options` and `X-Content-Type-Options` headers are overridden.

But if I have an unhandled exception in my code, then I get these headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2018 18:35:49 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: -1
```

So headers are not overridden.

Why is that? Is it by design? Does Exceptions middleware work differently so it doesn't go through the whole pipeline?

```
dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.4)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.1.4
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  5e8add2190

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.5
  Build    : 17373eb129b3b05aa18ece963f8795d65ef8ea54
```

Comment: Yes, this is by design and needs to be taken into account, also for CORS etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more reliable way to set the headers in any case would be to use the `OnStarting` callback. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.onstarting?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

> Adds a delegate to be invoked just before response headers will be sent to the client.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Server", "ololo");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

    await _next(context);
}
```

`OnStarting` will be invoked, just before the response headers are written to the wire. This allows you to set the headers after the exception middleware did handle it

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you. I read about `OnStarting()`, but I didn't understand it. Time to read more carefully.

Comment: Weird enough, I have another computer, and when I access the website from it, I get `An item with the same key has already been added. Key: X-Frame-Options`. I checked other devices - everywhere it's fine, just this one machine causes the problem.

Comment: Maybe related with XSRF (Cross-site request forgery ) when you do post requests? In this case the AntiForgery Token/filter will kick in. Could be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40526551/455493. In this case you may of course want to check if the header is set and not set it again (or just change its value) or like in the linked answer disable the header on the antiforgery middleware

Comment: Most probably it is. I've added the check for the header being already set and now it's all fine with that other computer too. Thank you again.